# Paint Component Not Drawing Oval

Tags: java, paintcomponent

Ok so I'm currently making a snakes and ladders game for a project and I have encountered a problem in which I was never faced before with. I have a class called Player which would be a circle on the game board.

The paintComponent method should be printing true constantly however, it does not

```
public class Player extends JComponent {
    private double playerX;
    private double playerY;
    private double diameter;
    private String playerColor;
    HashMap<String, Color> colorMap = new HashMap();

    public Player(String playerColor, double playerX, double playerY, double diameter) {
        this.playerColor = playerColor;
        this.playerX = playerY;
        this.playerY = playerY;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        setSize(getPreferredSize());
        setLocation((int) diameter, (int) diameter);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension((int) diameter * 2, (int) diameter * 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        g2d.drawOval((int) playerX, (int) playerY, (int) diameter * 2, (int) diameter * 2);
        System.out.println(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr I hope that is what you were looking for. The problem is that paintComponent is printing out true only once which is why it isn't drawing

Comment: How is that "complete"? I can't compile and test the code. `The problem is that paintComponent isn't printing out true` - Well,, the problem is the context of how you actually use the component. How do you actually add the component to the frame.  The code you posted looks reasonable, maybe the radius is 0? Maybe the problem is the layout manager? Without seeing the whole picture we would just be guessing what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not extend `JComponent` to create a new component, but to customize the painting process by overriding `paintComponent(..)`.

If you want to create a new component with its custom painting scheme, use a `JPanel` and override the `paint(..)` method.

```
public class Player extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private double playerX;
    private double playerY;
    private double diameter;
    private String playerColor;
    HashMap<String, Color> colorMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Player(String playerColor, double playerX, double playerY, double diameter) {
        this.playerColor = playerColor;
        this.playerX = playerY;
        this.playerY = playerY;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        setSize(getPreferredSize());
        setLocation((int) diameter, (int) diameter);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension((int) diameter * 2, (int) diameter * 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        g2d.drawOval((int) playerX, (int) playerY, (int) diameter * 2, (int) diameter * 2);
        System.out.println(true);
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592169/7709086).

Comment: paintComponent may still be the right thing to override depending on what he is doing. You are right that he should use something like JPanel as the base though